# How can i print specific elements from dictionary depending on input and relation to list?

Tags: python-3.x

My problem is that i have 1 list which includes a bunch of different subjects. I am trying to find a way to print specific element(s) from a dictionary if the input's that are given is a valid subject, then print all the sub-subjects related to that subject, as well as to check if the number starts with 1, 2 or 3. so lets say we have the subject "Information Science", and we give that as input, as well as i give "1" as an input, then i want to display all the subjects related to "Information Science".

As my knowledge is not the best at the moment. I've tried doing multiple solutions. Ive tried using for loops and if statements to find the specific elements etc, but was not satisfied with the answer.

```py
fagOmr = ['Informasjonsvitenskap', 'Økonomi']
emner = {"INFO100":"C", "INFO104":"B", "ECON100":"B"}

class fagFelt:

    def info_fag(velg_fag, niv):
        print('Velg handling')
        for i in emner:
            if velg_fag == [val for key, val in emner.items() if velg_fag in key] :
                print(i, emner[i])
            if velg_fag == [val for key, val in emner.items() if velg_fag in key] :
                print(i, emner[i])
```

The output i expect if i wrote "Informasjonsvitenskap" & "1". then i want the output.

'
INFO100 C
INFO104 B
'

For some reason i cant get the code formatting to work, so ill just explain. "INFO100 C" & "INFO104 B" should be seperated on different lines

Comment: you used ' instead of ` for code formatting.

Comment: Can you create sample input with the wanted output?

Comment: what do you mean @Frank ?

Comment: Like give an example of an input?

Comment: How does this Informasjonsvitenskap relate to INFO100 or INFO104? Or if you type in Økonomi as the input, how is the program supposed to know it should translate to ECON? So if I understand correctly, you need: fagOmr = { "Informasjonsvitenskap": "INFO", 'Økonomi' :'ECON'} for a start, right? Then I do not understand the role of the input of '1'.

Comment: Sorry i've seen that you have already an example. But i don't understand how the relation is between "Informasjonsvitenskap" & "1" and ' INFO100 C INFO104 B '. Do you have a dict={"Informasjonsvitenskap": ['INFO100 C', 'INFO104 B ']} ?

Comment: That actually makes alot of sence. yes, that would be better Petr

Comment: yes, lets use that as a standpoint, with creating that dictionary like: {'Informasjonsvitenskap':"INFO"}

Comment: and no @Frank i do not have a dict called dict={"iformasjonsvitenskap":['INFO100 C', 'INFO104 B']}

Comment: i mean a dict with some name={"iformasjonsvitenskap":['INFO100 C', 'INFO104 B']}

Comment: @Frank no i do not have a dictionary like that.

Comment: @PetrBlahos i think we can use your example as a starting point

Comment: @PetrBlahos the relation with "1" is basicly. each subject includes 3 numbers. the first of those numbers is the difficulty level of that subject. lets 1 is easy, 2 is mediocre, and 3 is hard